Solving the integral $\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}} \ dx$
My textbook has the following problem:
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}} \ dx$$
Using the trigonometric identity:
$$\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$$
the integration simplifies to:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \left( \sqrt{\tan x} + \sqrt{\cot x} \right) \ dx$$
I'm stuck here.

One method is to find the indefinite integration...but that is inelegant imo

\begin{align}
 &\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\sin x +\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}} \ dx\\
=&\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{d(\sin x -\cos x)}{\sqrt{1-(\sin x -\cos x)^2}} \\
=& \ \arcsin(\sin x -\cos x)\bigg|_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}
=2\arcsin\frac{\sqrt3-1}2
\end{align}

(+1) The solution can be further simplified to $\arccos(\sqrt3-1)$ or $\arctan\frac{\sqrt[4]3}{\sqrt2}$

Not quite as fast, but we can simplify the numerator first by substituting $x\to x+\dfrac\pi4$:
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_\tfrac\pi6^\tfrac\pi3 \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin(2x)}} \, dx \\
&= \int_{-\tfrac\pi{12}}^\tfrac\pi{12} \frac{\sqrt2\,\cos x}{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}} \, dx \\
&= 2\sqrt2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi{12} \frac{d(\sin x)}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2x}}
\end{align*}$$
Easy enough, but we can further simplify the integral by substituting $\sin x=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\sin y$:
$$I = 2\sqrt2 \int_0^{\arcsin\tfrac{\sqrt3-1}2} \frac{\cos y}{\sqrt2 \sqrt{1-\sin^2y}} \, dy = 2\arcsin\frac{\sqrt3-1}2 = \boxed{\arccos\left(\sqrt3-1\right)}$$
This follows from the double angle identity:
$$\sin\dfrac\pi{12}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos\frac\pi6}2} \\
\arcsin x=\dfrac12\arccos\left(1-2x^2\right)$$
